# Rails namespace controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've created a new page and for some reason i cannot find it.

I've used `rails generate controller dashboard index` Which worked fine. I then went into the routes file and added this

```
namespace :dashboard do
  get 'dashboard' => 'dashboard#index'
end
```

My file tree is like this
views --> dashboard --> index.html.erb

My helper is just this

```
module DashboardHelper
end
```

my controller has just got the `def index end` inside

Any ideas what im doing wrong?

if i go to /dashboard i get this error
`No route matches [GET] "/dashboard"`

Cheers

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: Sorry i'll add that in now

Comment: try /dashboard/dashboard

Comment: uninitialized constant Dashboard::DashboardController

Comment: if get 'dashboard' => 'dashboard#index' outside namespace in your routes it will work, else your controller should have Dashboard::DashboardController < ApplicationController and views folder structure should be /dashboard/dashboard/index.html.erb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are use a namespace option in routes.rb, you should wrap your controller class in namespace also you should put it in own folders.

To make it faster delete your current controller:

```
rails destroy controller dashboard
```

And generate new:

```
rails generate controller dashboard/dashboard index
```

Rails generate for you controller, inserts the right routes and add views.

```
$> rails generate controller dashboard/dashboard index
#> create  app/controllers/dashboard/dashboard_controller.rb
#>  route  namespace :dashboard do
#>    get 'dashboard/index'
#>  end
#> invoke  erb
#> create    app/views/dashboard/dashboard
#> create    app/views/dashboard/dashboard/index.html.erb
```

Comment: So i followed this, Then went to dashboard/dashboard and nothing worked got this error `ActionController::RoutingError at /dashboard/dashboard
uninitialized constant Dashboard::Controller`

Comment: do you restart  the server? and actual route url `dashboard/dashboard/index` according routes.rb

Answer (score 0):

Your `dashboard controller` should be

```
class Dashboard::DashboardController < ApplicationController
   def index
   end
end
```

Your `view folder structure` should be

```
views -> dashboard -> dashboard -> index.html.erb
```